# How Do I Anchor tag in XSLT?

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am lost as how to introduce anchor tag links to my code. This is not familiar territory as it is just an idea I came up with to make this project a little easier. So when I click the link up in the header table it will page jump to the picture of each tour. Just like how wikipedia does it for their sections of text. I created the names to be referenced by but I don't understand how it can be linked as I used a for-each loop to get the correct picture to display with each tour. Help is greatly appreciated.

XML

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="tour.xsl" ?>
<tours>
   <tour>
      <description>
         <p><i>Travel Scotland!</i> Goes south to England and the Lake District.
         The tour leaves departs from London, taking an overnight train to Windemere,
         your gateway to the Lake District. Take some time to peruse the local
         shops or hike the mountains, following in the footsteps of William
         Wordsworth. With a week in the Lake District, you'll have plenty of time
         to discover all of its charms and wonders.</p>
         <p>From the Lake District, we go to York for two fun-filled days. Tour the
         awesome York Minster, one of the most beautiful cathedrals in Europe. York
         is also home to underground ruins of one of the earliest Roman settlements
         in Britain.</p>
         <p>The tour concludes with two days of sight-seeing and fun in London.</p>
      </description>
      <tourName>The Lake District</tourName>
      <tourPhoto>Lake.jpg</tourPhoto>
      <tourGuide>Mary Taylor</tourGuide>
      <tdEmail>mailto:mtaylor@tscotland.com</tdEmail>
      <tourStart>6/15/2003</tourStart>
      <tourEnd>6/19/2003</tourEnd>
      <itinerary>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>1</dayNumber>
            <plan>London arrival</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>2</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Windemere</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>3</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day in Windemere</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>4</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Ambleside</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>5</dayNumber>
            <plan>Hiking tour to Grasmere</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>6</dayNumber>
            <plan>Boating trip on Lake Windemere</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>7</dayNumber>
            <plan>Free day</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>8</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Keswick and Honister Pass</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>9</dayNumber>
            <plan>Return to Ambleside</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>10</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to York</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>11</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day in York</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>12</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to London</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>13</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day in London</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>14</dayNumber>
            <plan>London departure</plan>   
         </day>
      </itinerary>   
   </tour>
   <tour>
     <description>
         <p>Join <i>Travel Scotland!</i> For a two-week tour of the Hebrides. The trip
         takes you to four of the beautiful Hebridean islands, including Fingal's
         Cave, featured in Medelssohn's <i>The Hebrides</i> Overture.</p>
         <p>The tour starts with a train tour of the Highlands from Glasgow to Fort
         William. After an overnight stay in Fort William, we leave by train and ferry
         to the Isle of Skye. While there, you'll have a chance to tour Dunvegan
         Castle and visit the Black Cullins in southern Skye. A boat trip to Mallaig
         follows and tour through Moidart where we'll visit the most western point in
         Great Britain.</p>
         <p>No tour of the Hebrides can be complete with a visit to Iona and Fingal's
         Cave. Plenty of time will be available for touring the abbey at Iona and 
         touring the ruins. Pay your respects at the grave of St. Columba who, as
         the legends tell it, was a disciple of St. Patrick and brought Christianity
         to the Highlands.</p>
         <p>You'll spend the next three days in Oban and on the Isle of Jura. Be sure
         to take some time to sample its world-famous scotch! The
         trip concludes with two days in Glasgow.</p>
      </description>
      <tourName>The Hebrides</tourName>
      <tourPhoto>Hebrides.jpg</tourPhoto>
      <tourGuide>Alan Simpson</tourGuide>
      <tdEmail>mailto:asimpson@tscotland.com</tdEmail>
      <tourStart>7/02/2003</tourStart>
      <tourEnd>7/16/2003</tourEnd>
      <itinerary>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>1</dayNumber>
            <plan>Glasgow arrival</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>2</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Fort William</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>3</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train and boat ferry to the Isle of Skye</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>4</dayNumber>
            <plan>Tour of Skye</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>5</dayNumber>
            <plan>Boat trip to Mallaig, bus tour through Moidart</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>6</dayNumber>
            <plan>Boat trip to the Isle of Mull</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>7</dayNumber>
            <plan>Free day</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>8</dayNumber>
            <plan>Tour of Iona and Fingal's Cave</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>9</dayNumber>
            <plan>Boat trip to Oban</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>10</dayNumber>
            <plan>Bus and boat tour to Jura</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>11</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day on Jura</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>12</dayNumber>
            <plan>Bus tour to Glasgow</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>13</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day in Glasgow</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>14</dayNumber>
            <plan>Glasgow departure</plan>   
         </day>
      </itinerary>   
   </tour>
   <tour>
     <description>
         <p>The <i>Highlands Tour</i> Continues to be our most popular tour. This
         two-week excursion takes you to some of the most awe-inspiring
         scenery in Scotland; yet provides plenty of shopping time and sight-seeing
         in the beautiful city of Edinburgh.</p>
         <p>The trip begins with two days in Glencoe, the site of the famous
         massacre of the MacDonald clan by the Stewarts. Take some time to go hiking.
         Several movies have been filmed in Glencoe, including <i>Braveheart</i> and
         <i>Highlander</i>. Maybe you'll get a chance to be an extra in this year's
         production!</p>
         <p>From Glencoe, the tour travels north, following the trail of Bonnie
         Prince Charlie to Glenfinnan. You'll also take a boat trip to view castle
         ruins along the Kyle of Lochalsh. A trip to Loch Ness follows. Perhaps
         you'll see Nessie!</p>
         <p>For city-dwellers, you'll enjoy the next three days in Edinburgh. Do some
         shopping along the Royal Mile, or climb Arthur's Seat for a awesome view of
         the city. If you love castles, visit Edinburgh castle and Sterling castle too.</p>
         <p>The tour concludes with a trip to Glasgow.</p>
      </description>
      <tourName>The Highlands</tourName>
      <tourPhoto>Highland.jpg</tourPhoto>
      <tourGuide>Geoff Rawlings</tourGuide>
      <tdEmail>mailto:grawlings@tscotland.com</tdEmail>
      <tourStart>7/07/2003</tourStart>
      <tourEnd>7/21/2003</tourEnd>
      <itinerary>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>1</dayNumber>
            <plan>Glasgow arrival</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>2</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Glencoe</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>3</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day in Glencoe</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>4</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Fort William and Glenfinnan</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>5</dayNumber>
            <plan>Boat ride through the Kyle of Lochalsh</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>6</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Loch Ness and Fort William</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>7</dayNumber>
            <plan>Free day</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>8</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Aviemore and Pitlochry</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>9</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Edinburgh</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>10</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day in Edinburgh</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>11</dayNumber>
            <plan>Third day in Edinburgh</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>12</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Sterling</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>13</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Glasgow</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>14</dayNumber>
            <plan>Glasgow departure</plan>   
         </day>
      </itinerary>   
   </tour>
   <tour>
     <description>
         <p>Do you like castles? The <i>Castles of Scotland Tour</i> is for you. The
         tour visits 15 differents castles in central and northern Scotland. The tour
         starts with the famous Edinburgh Castle, and <i>Travel Scotland!</i> has a
         special arrangement to visit parts of the castle normally closed to the
         public.</p>
         <p>From Edinburgh you travel to Stirling Castle with breathtaking views of
         the River Forth as it divides Scotland's Highlands and Lowlands. Inverness
         is next on the Itinerary with a side trip to Culloden to view where the
         campaign of Bonnie Prince Charlie came to an end.</p>
         <p>Look for Nessie from Castle Urquhart on the banks of Loch Ness. From there
         goes into the heart of the Highlands with trips to Fort William and Oban. We've
         made special plans to picnic by Castle Stalker near Glencoe.</p>
         <p>No castle tour would be complete with a trip to Balmacara Castle on the
         Isle of Skye. While on Skye, we'll have a boat trip along the feet of the
         Black Cullins.</p>
         <p>The tour concludes with two days back in Edinburgh for shopping, additional
         site-seeing, or just rest and relaxation.</p>
      </description>
      <tourName>Castles of Scotland</tourName>
      <tourPhoto>Castles.jpg</tourPhoto>
      <tourGuide>Alice Arthur</tourGuide>
      <tdEmail>mailto:aarthur@tscotland.com</tdEmail>
      <tourStart>8/01/2003</tourStart>
      <tourEnd>8/15/2003</tourEnd>
      <itinerary>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>1</dayNumber>
            <plan>Edinburgh arrival</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>2</dayNumber>
            <plan>Tour of Edinburgh Castle</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>3</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Sterling Castle</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>4</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Inverness</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>5</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day in Inverness</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>6</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Loch Ness and Fort William</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>7</dayNumber>
            <plan>Free day</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>8</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Castle Stalker and Oban</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>9</dayNumber>
            <plan>Trip to Glenfinnan, boat ride to the Isle of Skye</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>10</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day on Skye. Trip to Balmacara Castle</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>11</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Perth</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>12</dayNumber>
            <plan>Train to Edinburgh</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>13</dayNumber>
            <plan>Second day in Edinburgh</plan>
         </day>
         <day>
            <dayNumber>14</dayNumber>
            <plan>Edinburgh departure</plan>   
         </day>
      </itinerary>   
   </tour>
</tours>
```

Here is the XSLT:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" version="4.0"/>

<!-- Start of root template -->

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
        <title>Chan Brothers</title>
        <link href="tour.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
        <table border="2" align="center">
                <tr>
                        <th colspan="4">World Tour Inc. Tour List<br/>
                        <img src="logo.png" align="center" width="100"></img>
                        </th>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td> <a href="#Lake">Lake District</a> </td>
                        <td> <a href="#Hebrides">The Hebrides </a> </td>
                        <td> <a href="#Highlands">The Highlands </a> </td>
                        <td> <a href="#Castles">Castles of Scotland </a> </td>
                </tr>
        </table>
<xsl:apply-templates select="tours/tour"></xsl:apply-templates>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<!-- End of root template -->
<!-- Tour template -->
<xsl:template match="tour">
<div id="content">
<h2>
        <xsl:value-of select="tourName" />
        (Tour Guide: <xsl:value-of select="tourGuide" />)
</h2>
<xsl:for-each select="description/p[1]">
        <p>
        <img src="{../../tourPhoto}"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </p>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="description/p[position() &gt; 1]">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="tourStart">
        <table border="2" align="center">
                <tr>
                        <th>Start Date:</th>
                        <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
                </tr>
        </table>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="tourEnd">
        <table border="2" align="center">
                <tr>
                        <th>End Date:</th>
                        <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
                </tr>
        </table>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="tdEmail">
        <table border="2" align="center">
                <tr>
                        <th>Email:</th>
                        <th><xsl:value-of select="."/></th>
                </tr>
        </table>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:apply-templates select="itinerary" />
</div>
</xsl:template>
<!-- End Tour template -->
<!-- Section templates -->
<xsl:template match="itinerary">
<table border="3" align="center">
<tr>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Destination</th>
</tr>
<th>
<xsl:apply-templates select="day/dayNumber" />
</th>
<tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="plan" />
</tr>
</table>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="day|dayNumber">
<tr><xsl:value-of select="." /></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="plan">
<tr><xsl:value-of select="." /></tr>
</xsl:template>
<!-- End Section templates -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Lastly my CSS

```css
body    
h1, h2  {font-family: sans-serif; width: 640px}
h1      {text-align: center; margin: -10px; padding: 0px}
h2      {margin-top: -5px}
div     {width: 700px; border: 1px solid black; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; background-color: cyan}
p img   {width: 200px; float: left; margin: 0px 15px 0px 0px}
p       {text-align: justify}
table   {background-color: white; width: 400px}
th      {font-family: sans-serif; color: navy}
td      {text-align: center}
#content {margin-left: auto ; margin-right: auto}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can create anchors linking your top navigation table to the actual items:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/tours">
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Chan Brothers</title>
            <link href="tour.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <table border="2" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="{count(tour)}">World Tour Inc. Tour List<br/>
                        <img src="logo.png" align="center" width="100"></img>
                    </th>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="tour" mode="nav"/>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="tour"/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tour" mode="nav">
     <td><a href="#{generate-id()}"><xsl:value-of select="tourName"/></a></td>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tour">
    <a name="{generate-id()}"/>
    <div id="content">
    <!-- the rest of the template  -->
</xsl:template>

<!-- other templates -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I suggest you post your other question separately, as it seems unrelated to this one.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will edit my post and work on what you have provided me.